# Trouble with background colours distinguishing between letters and numbers

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to change the background colour of a cell based on its contents. We are looking at grades, either 'A to U' or '9 to 1'. The cell needs to be highlighted if the grades are 2 lower than their target grade. We have it working if the cells are just numbers or just letters but not both.

Here is the Custom Code for the report:

```
Public Function gradeCheck(SubjectGrade AS String, TargetGrade AS String) AS String

Dim gradeValue = convertGradeToInt(SubjectGrade)
Dim targetValue = convertGradeToInt(TargetGrade)

If (targetValue - gradeValue) < -1
    Return "Orange"
Else
    Return "White"
End If  
End Function

Public Function gradeCheckInt(SubjectGradeInt AS Integer, TargetGradeInt AS Integer) AS String

If (TargetGradeInt - SubjectGradeInt) >= 2
    Return "Orange"
Else
    Return "White"
End If  
End Function    

Public Function convertGradeToInt(grade AS String) AS Integer

Select Case grade
    Case "A*"
        return 1
    Case "A"
        return 2
    Case "B"
        return 3
    Case "C"
        return 4
    Case "D"
        return 5
    Case "E"
        return 6
    Case "F"
        return 7
    Case "G"
        return 8
    Case "U"
        return 9
End Select
End Function
```

Here is the code that works for numbers on their own or letters on their own:

Letters
    = IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!report_Grade.Value)
    , "White"
    , IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!TargetGrade.Value)
        , "White"
        ,code.gradeCheck(Fields!report_Grade.Value, Fields!TargetGrade.Value)
        )
    )

Numbers

```
= IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!report_Grade.Value)
, "White"
, IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!TargetGrade.Value)
    , "White"
    ,code.gradeCheckInt(Fields!report_Grade.Value, Fields!TargetGrade.Value)
    )
)
```

And here is what I feel should work, but is only highlighting the correct numbers, not letters:

```
= IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!report_Grade.Value)
    , "White"
    , IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!TargetGrade.Value)
        , "White"
        ,IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!report_Grade.Value)
            ,code.gradeCheckInt(Fields!report_Grade.Value, Fields!TargetGrade.Value)
            ,code.gradeCheck(Fields!report_Grade.Value, Fields!TargetGrade.Value)
        )
    )
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your grades always come from the same column so this must be a string (even if it contains a number). If this is the case then I would modify your `convertGradeToInt` function by testing if the string is a value something like

```
Public Function convertGradeToInt(grade AS String) AS Integer

    If Val(grade) > 0 then
        return Val(grade)
    ELSE

        Select Case grade
            Case "A*"
                return 1
            Case "A"
                return 2
            Case "B"
                return 3
            Case "C"
                return 4
            Case "D"
                return 5
            Case "E"
                return 6
            Case "F"
                return 7
            Case "G"
                return 8
            Case "U"
                return 9
        End Select
    End If
End Function
```

Now, if the passed in value is numeric you just get the same value back, if it's a string it returns the matching grade (or zero if not match found).

Now your color expression can be simple

```
=IIF(Code.convertGradeToInt(Fields!TargetGrade.Value) - Code.convertGradeToInt(Fields!report_Grade.Value) >= 2 , "Orange", Nothing)
```

You should not need any other code, just the one function and one expression for the colour.

I may have overlooked something as it's not tested but hopefully it will give you enough to solve the problem.

Comment: This was it! This was the missing piece of the puzzle! I had to make a couple of changes to fit in with the rest but this is what I've been looking for all week! You have no idea how happy I am to finally have this working. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Alan above I was able to make it work. Here is the final custom code I used:

```
Here is the final custom code I used:

Public Function gradeCheck(SubjectGrade AS Integer, TargetGrade AS Integer) AS String

If TargetGrade - SubjectGrade >= 2 
    Return "Orange"
Else
    Return "White"
End If  
End Function


Public Function convertGradeToInt(grade AS String) AS Integer

If Val(grade) > 0 then
    return Val(grade)
ELSE

    Select Case grade
        Case "A*"
            return 9
        Case "A"
            return 8
        Case "B"
            return 7
        Case "C"
            return 6
        Case "D"
            return 5
        Case "E"
            return 4
        Case "F"
            return 3
        Case "G"
            return 2
        Case "U"
            return 1
    End Select
End If
End Function
```

And here is the colour expression:

```
= IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!report_Grade.Value)
    , "White"
    , IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!TargetGrade.Value)
        , "White"
        , code.gradeCheck(Code.convertGradeToInt(Fields!report_Grade.Value), Code.convertGradeToInt(Fields!TargetGrade.Value))
    )
)
```

Comment: Glad you got it working but I don't think you need your gradecheck function at all. You can do the whole thing in a very simple expression. Anyway it's your call, it just seems overly complicated to me for no obvious reason.

Comment: I'm just starting out and have been told I over complicate things, but at the moment if it works I'm happy to leave it for now and come back and have a play with it when I have some free time. I'm making a list of all the code here which looks like it could be streamlined and saving it for a rainy day.